# How to sdd timstamps to each rows

Tags: python, pycharm, timestamp, mediapipe

I want to  to add a timestamps in milliseconds for each row :
This is the file I want to add timstamps to:

```
 csv_path = 'keypoint_output1.csv'
            with open(csv_path, 'a', newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow([*pre_processed_landmark_list])
```

I have tried to add current time using this code
However this only add the starting run time for each row but not the real time

```
1  2  2023-02-11 12:45:10.557105 
1  2  2023-02-11 12:45:10.557105
1  2  2023-02-11 12:45:10.557105
1  2  2023-02-11 12:45:10.557105




curr_time = datetime.now()
                formatted_time = curr_time.strftime('%M:%S.%f')
                with open("keypoint_output1.csv", "r") as fin, open("out.csv",        ``'w', newline='') as fout:
                    reader = csv.reader(fin)
                    writer = csv.writer(fout)
                    for line in reader:
                        line.append(curr_time)
                        writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you are getting the current time only once, which is then saved in the variable `curr_time`. That variable will store the exact same time as long as you do not assign the time again.

To counter this and get the current time at each iteration, you need to reassign the current time to the variable (`curr_time`) again, before you write the row:

```py
csv_path = 'keypoint_output1.csv'
with open(csv_path, 'a', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for pre_processed_landmark in pre_processed_landmark_list:
        curr_time = datetime.now()
        formatted_time = curr_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        writer.writerow([*pre_processed_landmark, formatted_time])
```